# What should be placed into the AssemblyTrademarkAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net

Visual Studio generates this set of attributes for a C# assembly by default:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ContosoApp")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Contoso's latest great product.")]
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Contoso Corporation")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ContosoApp Suite")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Contoso 2012")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")] // ??
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

I have no idea what makes "Trademark" different from "Company" here. What should be placed here?

Comment: A single company can have many trademarks. Product and trademark are probably more similar. If you don't know what to put in trademark you probably don't have a registered trademark then. Leave it empty. Trademark is a legal registered name of a product. Coca cola company owns the Sprite trademark.

Comment: @Andrew: Perhaps I should have clarified -- I know what a trademark is. But I don't know what it has to do with assemblies.

Comment: @BillONeal Most of those are just metadata that you can look at when you click on the file, or process it in some way. You can put whatever you want in there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have three fields of interest here: company name, product name and trademark.

The company name is quite obvious what it is, and so is the product name. The trademark, however, is more ambiguous. According to [this article](http://www.businesslink.gov.uk/bdotg/action/detail?itemId=1073791334&type=RESOURCES) the trademark could either be:

- Your company name, which is protected intellectual property by default (in most countries)
- Your product name, which may or may not be protected intellectual property
- Something else irrelevant to the question.

A product name can be protected IP if you have registered it as a trademark. Microsoft Office is a great example of a protected product name/trademark. In this case only you as the owner may use the product name for your products. By default, however, a product name is not protected IP and can be used by any person or company that wish to use it.

In your case you have a registered (and protected) product name or trademark and it seems very reasonable to use that for both `AssemblyProduct` and `AssemblyTrademark`. In case you your product name would not be protected IP it feels unreasonable to put it in the `AssemblyTrademark` as others may use this product name as well. In this case I would put my company name or leave it empty.

Comment: Yes, but how does that relate to assemblies. Contoso has a trademark, so what? How does that apply to an assembly that's getting generated?

Comment: My answer targets your statement "I have no idea what makes "Trademark" different from "Company" here.". I try to highlight the difference. As someone said, to my understanding, a trademark is often (but not always) more similar to a product than the company name. However, in your comment you state that you know what a trademark is, which renders this answer useless. I'll delete it in a bit.

Comment: Hmm, just rewrote the whole thing, got your comment in the middle.. Is this better or worse than before? Feel free to rollback if you preferred the old one :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at Microsoft's [trademark page](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/Trademarks/EN-US.aspx), I would think it is Intellectual Property related or named trademarks like where they have 'Office' and 'Hotmail'

Comment: So, that should be set to something like the product name?

Comment: broken link in answer : 

We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.
The URL may be misspelled or the page you're looking for is no longer available.